# How can I remove a sim lock when I'm no longer an Orange France customer?

Tags: iphone, unlock, sim

I bought an iPhone 4 in France. When moving to Belgium, I've put a belgian SIM card but I noticed that the phone is SIMLOCKED. I contacted the person who sold it to me and explained everything. He proposed me to contact Orange France to UNLOCK the iPhone.

I tried to contact them but couldn't reach them.

If someone experienced the same problem, please tell me how you fixed this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you already try all the steps described in http://assistance.orange.fr/desimlocker-votre-mobile-2839.php?

Comment: I couldn't do this because I don't have a French number

Comment: Close to the bottom of the page: "Si vous n'êtes plus client Orange mobile, pour désimlocker votre mobile, vous devez envoyer un courrier à l'adresse postale suivante :
Orange service clients Mobile
41965 BLOIS CEDEX 9..."

Comment: And if you keep the page open long enough, a dialog box pops up asking whether you need online assistance. May get faster results than sending a letter.

Comment: Your comments seem to be the solutions/answers to my question. Especially your second comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://assistance.orange.fr/desimlocker-votre-mobile-2839.php:

> **obtenir le code de désimlockage pour les anciens clients Orange mobile**
>
> Si vous n'êtes plus client Orange mobile, pour désimlocker votre mobile, vous devez envoyer un courrier à l'adresse postale suivante :

```
Orange service clients Mobile
41965 BLOIS CEDEX 9
```

> Dans ce courrier, précisez : votre nom, prénom, adresse mail, numéro de mobile résilié et le numéro IMEI à 15 chiffres du mobile concerné par votre demande.